# Client side functions doesn't call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I had lot of difficulties after upgrading signalR & .NET version.
Previously I had 1.XX version now I have 2.4.0 signal R version.

This question is directly connected with - https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/4339

But after upgrade signal R doesn't work.

Now the problem is client-side functions cannot call.

I just tried this: [Signalr doesn't call client side functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15071826/signalr-doesnt-call-client-side-functions/15074002)

and fixed it according to the correct answer:

> In your init prior to $.connection.hub.start call your _subscribe method.

Later I went through a bit deeper down on this issue, and added console.log below place in my signalr.js

```
connection.socket.onmessage = function (event) {
    var data;

    try {
        console.log(event.data);
        data = connection._parseResponse(event.data);
    }
    catch (error) {
        transportLogic.handleParseFailure(connection, event.data, error, onFailed, event);
        console.log("socket error" + event.data);
        return;
    }

    if (data) {
        transportLogic.processMessages(connection, data, onSuccess);
    }
};
```

After every one joins meeting -> meeting start and ask for vote (this place we should call signalR)

From vote asking person side I see console log like this:

Normal user ( voting persons console log looks like this:

This is from Firefox - another user:

I think it already triggering - client hub event 'sendOnlineMeetingVoteRequest' on hub 'NotificationHub'.

It already hit server-side function too but the thing is it never hits this part of the code:

```
notificationHub.client.sendOnlineMeetingVoteRequest = function (token, meetingId, meetingVoteId) {
    debugger;
    if (token == '@Model.Organization' && '@Model.MeetingId' == meetingId) {
        ShowMeetingOnlineMeetingVotePopup(meetingId, meetingVoteId);
    }
};
```

I went through http://localhost:33852/signalr/hubs

```
/*!
 * ASP.NET SignalR JavaScript Library v2.3.0-rtm
 * http://signalr.net/
 *
 * Copyright (c) .NET Foundation. All rights reserved.
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0. See License.txt in the project root for license information.
 *
 */

/// <reference path="..\..\SignalR.Client.JS\Scripts\jquery-1.6.4.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.signalR.js" />
(function ($, window, undefined) {
    /// <param name="$" type="jQuery" />
    "use strict";

    if (typeof ($.signalR) !== "function") {
        throw new Error("SignalR: SignalR is not loaded. Please ensure jquery.signalR-x.js is referenced before ~/signalr/js.");
    }

    var signalR = $.signalR;

    function makeProxyCallback(hub, callback) {
        return function () {
            // Call the client hub method
            callback.apply(hub, $.makeArray(arguments));
        };
    }

    function registerHubProxies(instance, shouldSubscribe) {
        var key, hub, memberKey, memberValue, subscriptionMethod;

        for (key in instance) {
            if (instance.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                hub = instance[key];

                if (!(hub.hubName)) {
                    // Not a client hub
                    continue;
                }

                if (shouldSubscribe) {
                    // We want to subscribe to the hub events
                    subscriptionMethod = hub.on;
                } else {
                    // We want to unsubscribe from the hub events
                    subscriptionMethod = hub.off;
                }

                // Loop through all members on the hub and find client hub functions to subscribe/unsubscribe
                for (memberKey in hub.client) {
                    if (hub.client.hasOwnProperty(memberKey)) {
                        memberValue = hub.client[memberKey];

                        if (!$.isFunction(memberValue)) {
                            // Not a client hub function
                            continue;
                        }

                        // Use the actual user-provided callback as the "identity" value for the registration.
                        subscriptionMethod.call(hub, memberKey, makeProxyCallback(hub, memberValue), memberValue);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $.hubConnection.prototype.createHubProxies = function () {
        var proxies = {};
        this.starting(function () {
            // Register the hub proxies as subscribed
            // (instance, shouldSubscribe)
            registerHubProxies(proxies, true);

            this._registerSubscribedHubs();
        }).disconnected(function () {
            // Unsubscribe all hub proxies when we "disconnect".  This is to ensure that we do not re-add functional call backs.
            // (instance, shouldSubscribe)
            registerHubProxies(proxies, false);
        });

        proxies['NotificationHub'] = this.createHubProxy('NotificationHub'); 
        proxies['NotificationHub'].client = { };
        proxies['NotificationHub'].server = {

            sendMeetingStartMessage: function (token, meetingId) {
                return proxies['NotificationHub'].invoke.apply(proxies['NotificationHub'], $.merge(["sendMeetingStartMessage"], $.makeArray(arguments)));
             },

            sendMeetingStopMessage: function (token, meetingId) {
                return proxies['NotificationHub'].invoke.apply(proxies['NotificationHub'], $.merge(["sendMeetingStopMessage"], $.makeArray(arguments)));
             },

            sendMeetingTreeRefreshRequest: function (token, meetingId) {
                return proxies['NotificationHub'].invoke.apply(proxies['NotificationHub'], $.merge(["sendMeetingTreeRefreshRequest"], $.makeArray(arguments)));
             },

            sendMessage: function (token, meetingId, agendaGroupItemId, motionId) {
                return proxies['NotificationHub'].invoke.apply(proxies['NotificationHub'], $.merge(["sendMessage"], $.makeArray(arguments)));
             },

            sendOnlineMeetingVoteCloseRequest: function (token, meetingId, meetingVoteId) {
                return proxies['NotificationHub'].invoke.apply(proxies['NotificationHub'], $.merge(["sendOnlineMeetingVoteCloseRequest"], $.makeArray(arguments)));
             },

            sendOnlineMeetingVoteRequest: function (token, meetingId, meetingVoteId) {
                return proxies['NotificationHub'].invoke.apply(proxies['NotificationHub'], $.merge(["sendOnlineMeetingVoteRequest"], $.makeArray(arguments)));
             },

            sendOnlineVoteCloseRequest: function (token, meetingId, agendaGroupItemId, motionId) {
                return proxies['NotificationHub'].invoke.apply(proxies['NotificationHub'], $.merge(["sendOnlineVoteCloseRequest"], $.makeArray(arguments)));
             },


            sendOnlineVoteRequest: function (token, meetingId, agendaGroupItemId, motionId) {
                return proxies['NotificationHub'].invoke.apply(proxies['NotificationHub'], $.merge(["sendOnlineVoteRequest"], $.makeArray(arguments)));
             },


            sendOnlineVoteResult: function (token, meetingId, agendaGroupItemId, motionId, selectedVotingOptionId) {
                return proxies['NotificationHub'].invoke.apply(proxies['NotificationHub'], $.merge(["sendOnlineVoteResult"], $.makeArray(arguments)));
             }
        };

        return proxies;
    };

    signalR.hub = $.hubConnection("/signalr", { useDefaultPath: false });
    $.extend(signalR, signalR.hub.createHubProxies());

}(window.jQuery, window));
```

So I didn't found any error on it too.
Still, I cannot figure it out why this is happening but I went through the sample project that uses signalR 2.0.3.0 version

I went to reference & just noted that this reference - Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin is not included in that sample project that I downloaded.

I did some investigation furthermore & find out this:

> 'The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties'
>   This error will occur if a reference to Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin
>   is not removed. This package is deprecated; the reference must be
>   removed and the 1.x version of the SelfHost package must be
>   uninstalled.
>   (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/releases/upgrading-signalr-1x-projects-to-20)

Do I need to remove that?
In my web config, there is no code like this.

Answer (score 0):

I just call this function purely from another place - about us page. only add relevant script and function.
from that place, it worked.

after that, I changed some scripts placing and fix this issue.

the main thing is I didn't get any error or anything. thing looks working all the time. but because of some script placement, it doesn't work.