# Are there any sample projects out there showing how to use SignalR with a WinJS Windows 8.1 projects?

Tags: signalr, winjs

Are there any sample projects out there showing how to use SignalR with a WinJS Windows 8.1 projects?  NOT windows phone 8.1, just Windows 8.1 using WinJS.

I'm specifically looking for a sample project or code that shows how to push messages to all WinJS clients.

I have generated the hubs.js file and included it in my winjs project.  I am setting the $.connection.hub.url to the correct url.  I can see in fiddler that the connection as started.

But, for some reason, when I run the code to broadcast the message to all clients, nothing happens.  It's as if the server does not think there are any clients connected so it doesn't broadcast anything.

**Here is my server code from my Web Api project:**

Startup.cs

```
    // Branch the pipeline here for requests that start with "/signalr"
    app.Map("/signalr", map =>
    {
        // Setup the cors middleware to run before SignalR.
        // By default this will allow all origins. You can 
        // configure the set of origins and/or http verbs by
        // providing a cors options with a different policy.
        map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

        var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
        {
            EnableDetailedErrors = true,
            EnableJavaScriptProxies = false
        };

        // Run the SignalR pipeline. We're not using MapSignalR
        // since this branch is already runs under the "/signalr"
        // path.
        map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
    });
```

CommandsHub.cs

```
[HubName("remoteCommands")]
public class CommandsHub : Hub
{
}
```

ClientCommand.cs

```
public class ClientCommand
{
    public string ClientType { get; set; }
    public string CommandName { get; set; }
    public StringDictionary CommandParameters { get; set; }
}
```

CommandsController.cs (an ApiController used to allow an admin to broadcast to the clients)

```
    // POST api/values
    public void Post([FromBody]ClientCommand command)
    {
        var cmd = command ?? Notifier.GetTestMessageCommand();
        var notifier = new Notifier();
        notifier.PushCommand(cmd);
    }
```

Notifier.cs

```
public class Notifier
{
    public Notifier()
    {
        _context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<CommandsHub>();
    }
    public static ClientCommand GetTestMessageCommand()
    {
        var parameters = new StringDictionary();
        parameters.Add("title", "Message Title");
        parameters.Add("body", "Message Body");
        return new ClientCommand
        {
            ClientType = "XboxOne",
            CommandName = "ShowMessage",
            CommandParameters = parameters
        };

    }

    private IHubContext _context; 
    public void PushCommand(ClientCommand command)
    {
        if (_context == null)
        {
            _context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<CommandsHub>();
        }
        _context.Clients.All.executeRemoteCommand(command);
    }
}
```

The following line gets executed, but nothing seems to happen.  Fiddler doesn't show any network activity and the client method with the matching name does not get run.

```
_context.Clients.All.executeRemoteCommand(command);
```

**Here is the code from the client project:**

Via Nuget, I installed the Microsoft ASP.NET SignalR Javascript Client

I am also using the command

```
signalr.exe ghp /o:scripts\\hubs.js
```

to generate my hubs.js file and I'm including it in the WinJS project.

I added references in default.html to the following:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/hubs.js" defer="defer"></script>
<script src="js/SignalRConfig.js" defer="defer"></script>
```

SignalRConfig.js

(function signalRInit() {
    "use strict";

```
WinJS.Namespace.define("Starz", {
    RemoteCommands: WinJS.Class.define(
        function ctor() {
            $.connection.url = "http://starzsignlalr.test:19046/signalr"
            $.connection.hub.url = "http://starzsignlalr.test:19046/signalr";  //TODO: Change "http://starzsignlalr.test:19046/" to a valid website host name setup on your dev box that is running the SignalRMessageService web project.
            $.connection.hub.start().done(this._init);
        },
    {
        _init: function () {
            var hub = $.connection.remoteCommands;
            hub.client.executeRemoteCommand = Starz.RemoteCommands.executeRemoteCommand;
        }
    },
    {
        //add static properties and methods here.
        executeRemoteCommand: function (command) {
            var clientId = command.clientId;
            var commandName = command.commandName;
            var commandParameters = command.commandParameters;
        }
    }),
});
```

})();

In default.js, after the onactivated event, I call:

var pushSystem = new Starz.RemoteCommands();

This initializes the SignalR connection.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. I'm pretty sure that *out there* would constitute an *off-site resource*.

Comment: Show the server and client code and fiddler output, high-light the issue and you'll probably get more help.

Comment: Okay, I updated the question with all of the code you need to recreate what I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out my problem.  Apparently you have to register your client-side javascript methods with the hub client before you call $.connection.hub.start().

This post:

[SignalR JS Client Methods Not Invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072223/signalr-js-client-methods-not-invoked)

provided the answer.